# A problem on properties of Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Which properties hold for the following set?
Open, connected, dense, closed
$A$=$X\setminus\{x_0\}$  where $X$ is an arbitrary Hausdorff topological space and $x_0\in X$.

Since $X$ is hausdorff it is $T_1$hence $A$ is open. But how can I able to verify the other properties.

Comment: You could profit from working out a few examples, for instance $X=\Bbb R, x_0=0$, $X=\lbrace 0,1,2,\rbrace, x_0=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed, $T_{1}$ implies that $A$ is always open. For rest of the properties there is no definite answer and they depend on the topology of $X$.

For a demonstration of this let $X=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $x_{0}=0$. Assuming that $X$ has the discrete topology, then $A$ is closed, not dense and disconnected. But if we assume that $X$ has the Euclidean topology, then $A$ is not closed, dense and connected.

Answer (score 2):

$X \setminus \{x_0\}$ is dense iff $x_0$ is not an isolated point.
It is closed iff $x_0$ *is* an isolated point.
(which makes sense as a closed and dense subset of $X$ must equal $X$ by definition,
so it cannot be both)

As you said, it is always open (in a $T_1$ space).
For connected $X$, it is disconnected iff $x_0$ is a so-called non-cutpoint.
(contrast $\mathbb{R}$ vs $\mathbb{R}^2$).